# Getting an error when starting express server

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables, prisma, nodemon

I'm trying to run a typescript/express server (which also has prisma), and have different environment variables for different environments. I'm using [dotenv-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-cli), so that the correct env file can run on a command line level (because of prisma), when I run the following command:

```
dotenv -e .env.development -- nodemon src/index
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /usr/local/bin/dotenv:23:in `<main>'
        3: from /usr/local/bin/dotenv:23:in `load'
        2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/dotenv-2.7.6/bin/dotenv:4:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/dotenv-2.7.6/lib/dotenv/cli.rb:18:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/dotenv-2.7.6/lib/dotenv/cli.rb:34:in `parse_argv!': invalid option: e (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
        4: from /usr/local/bin/dotenv:23:in `<main>'
        3: from /usr/local/bin/dotenv:23:in `load'
        2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/dotenv-2.7.6/bin/dotenv:4:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/dotenv-2.7.6/lib/dotenv/cli.rb:18:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/dotenv-2.7.6/lib/dotenv/cli.rb:34:in `parse_argv!': invalid option: -e (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
```

How can I run `dotenv-cli` with typescript files and watch the files for changes?

Comment: `dotenv -e .env.development && nodemon src/index`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your ruby dotenv is taking precedence over the node dotenv-cli

Try this instead:

```
npx dotenv-cli -e .env.development -- nodemon src/index
```